# Determine exact properties applied by Button

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

Let's say I click a button in excel like comma formatting, is there a way to determine the exact styles it applies to the selection?

[I'm trying to avoid browsing the tree manually.](https://superuser.com/questions/1032893/view-source-code-microsoft-excel)

Alternatively if I set the font color to red although this is obvious is there a way to make a snap shot of properties of excel before and then after?

Comment: Please make your question more descriptive.

Comment: @Sixthsense Added another example

Comment: Yes you can by way of using PrintScreen maually or via code to take the snapshot.

Comment: @Sixthsense What code?  The property list is to long to take a snapshot.  I'm trying to avoid browsing the tree manually.

Comment: added code to do the snapshot and paste process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was surprised by this but you can basically start recording a macro under `View`->`Macros`->`Record Macros`.

The macro then gets dumped under alt+f11 under Module.
Here is an example.

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'

'
    Range("B9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("B10").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal _
  bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C
Private Const VK_MENU = &H12

Private Sub AltPrintScreen()
    keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, 0, 0
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0
    keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
    keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
End Sub
Sub TakeSnapshot()
    Call AltPrintScreen
    SendKeys "^v"
End Sub
```

Comment: I see why you are confused because I used the word snapshot.  You kinda ignored the rest of my question.  I just mean a snapshot of properties so I can compare the 2.  Not what I am asking.  Not an answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Still I don't understand what is your actual requirement.  I hope someone may help you better than me.

Comment: Do you know html & js?  Basically if you have the following button `<div onclick="document.getElmentById('i').style = 'color:green;background:orange;border:1px solid orange;'">test</div>` and press it it applies the styles to the #i element.  Now Word does something similar because you can see such properties.  I'm just trying to figure what styles it applies.

Comment: There is no control property exist in excel to take screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you just need to run a macro with the properties you want to view:

```
Sub TellMeAboutIt()
    Dim testRange
    Set testRange = Range("A1")

    Debug.Print testRange.Interior.Color
    Debug.Print testRange.Font.Size
    Debug.Print testRange.Font.Bold
    Debug.Print testRange.Font.Italic
    Debug.Print testRange.Row
    Debug.Print testRange.Column
    Debug.Print testRange.Style

End Sub
```

Just run it before and after you do something. Or attach it to an event. Or whatever. Take a look at [Range Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).

Comment: Is there something like equivalent to js's `for(i in x)` in visual basic?  I guess I could list all the properties but that seems like a lot of work.

Comment: Not as far as I know, each property has to be called, I think. If it's a class with properties you can, but otherwise no. You could copy the cell to a hidden sheet so you have all the formatting from before, though.

Comment: So it appears if you record a macro if writes the properties to a VBA script.  At least there is a way to get the properties with out browsing the property list manually.

Comment: If you record yourself doing it, it will record the new properties, but not the old ones, which I thought you wanted (both).